# The name 'rb2d' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

   public float maxSpeed = 10f;
   public float speed2f;

   // Use this for initialization
    void Start() 
       {
          rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    
       }

    void FixedUpdate()
       {
         float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

         rb2d.AddForce(Vector2.right * speed * h);

         Debug.Log(rb2d.velocity.x);

       }
}
```

En la línea (22,40) me marca este error:
The name 'rb2d' does not exist in the current context

Y en las demás líneas me marca este:
The name 'rb2d' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Es probable que esta pregunta termine cerrada, y sugiero revises el centro de ayuda para saber cómo preguntar y por qué esta respuesta no puede ser completamente respondida.

**Dicho esto.**

> Los errores son: Assets\Scrpts\PlayerController.cs(21,40): error
> CS0103: The name 'speed' does not exist in the current context

Esto significa que la variable o *identificador* no está declarado en ningún lugar y está siendo utilizado en la función `.AddForce`. Deberás declararla y asignarle un valor antes de utilizarla:

```
 var speed = 9.8;
```

> tambien este Assets\Scrpts\PlayerController.cs(21,10): error CS0103:
> The name 'rb2d' does not exist in the current context

Igual. Esa variable no está declarada. Deberás declarar la variable y asignarle un objeto antes de poder acceder a sus propiedades y sus métodos.

**Fin del edit**

---

Si te fijas, al inicio de tu clase tienes

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour{} // dos llaves
```

Las llaves indican el inicio y el fin de un bloque de código.

Al compilador le estás diciendo:

*Estoy declarando una clase llamada Player, que hereda de `MonoBehaviour` y esta es su definición....*

Y dentro no hay nada.

Tal vez quieras mover la llave de cierre al final de la clase. Así:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

   public float speed2f;

   // Use this for initialization
    void Start() 
       {
          rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    
       }

    void FixedUpdate()
       {
         float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

         rb2d.AddForce(Vector2.right * speed * h);

       }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, aunque me sigue marcando este error
Assets\Scrpts\PlayerController.cs(7,2): error CS1519: Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: Si sigues teniendo el mismo problema, entonces, tal vez no sea necesario marcar la respuesta como aceptada, todavía.

Comment: Este es el mismo archivo? Porque esta clase se llama `Player`. Te marca el error donde dice `PlayerController`. Puedes pegar el código de esa clase?

Comment: Gracias, no me había dado cuenta de lo que dices ahorita. Bien ahora me aparecen 3 errores. Perdón por las molestias es que soy principiante

Comment: Los errores son: Assets\Scrpts\PlayerController.cs(21,40): error CS0103: The name 'speed' does not exist in the current context

Comment: tambien este Assets\Scrpts\PlayerController.cs(21,10): error CS0103: The name 'rb2d' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Y este Assets\Scrpts\PlayerController.cs(13,11): error CS0103: The name 'rb2d' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Tendrías que pegar el código para que te podamos ayudar. De una vez te digo que puedes pasar por nuestro sitio de ayuda para aprender [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Tienes errores de sintaxis. Lee lo que te dice el compilador y actúa de acuerdo a ello

Comment: El código que me pasó en la respuesta o cual?

Comment: Tienes que pegar el código de `PlayerController.cs` porque ahí es donde tienes los tres errores.

Comment: Este es el codigo:

Comment: Ok. entonces, hay que estudiar un poco más. voy a editar la respuesta para ilustrar algunos conceptos.

Comment: Al ultimo modifique un poco el código agregándole una velocidad máxima pero me salio de nuevo el error CS0103

Comment: Al igual como hiciste con maxspeed y speed2f, debes declarar rb2d al inicio de la clase, como una propiedad

Comment: Gracias ya lo arregle muchas gracias es la primera vez que uso el sitio muchísimas gracias

Comment: Si mi respuesta ahora sí es satisfactoria, puedes tomarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas declarar la variable "rb2d" de tipo Rigidbody2D al inicio de tu clase:

```
private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
```